# What is the difference between true neutral and unaligned?

Tags: dnd-5e, alignment

Something I’ve never gotten is that true neutral and unaligned seem to be the same in the long run. The only difference is that unaligned is for wild animals, and true neutral is for intelligent creatures - one being driven by instinct and the other by choice.

**Similarities**

- Neither leans towards good or evil nor law vs. chaos
- Both do what seems right at the time

**Differences**

- The reasoning behind their action is the only one I can seem to find

Comment: Questions about alignment tend not to work well in the stack format unless they’re about the raw mechanics. This will likely get closed as POB.

Comment: This isn’t really opinion based it’s pretty factual. Asking where does x belong on the axis is opinion based. But this isn’t that. I’m asking what the difference between two seeming similar alignments are which isn’t opinion based. The first being morality and the second about how two things in a system are defined.

Comment: Related on [Can a PC be unaligned?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97472/can-a-pc-be-unaligned).

Comment: @indigochild I don't think it's dupe, they're not asking if they can be, they're asking how it's different from True Neutral.

Comment: unaligned is on most beast enemies in the srd and I have seen it defined as being for wild animals who act on instict without any good or evil intentions. (forget where)

Comment: @NautArch unaligned is not a pc option but it's on the majority of beast type enemies so it does at the very least exist.

Comment: While the morality angle may be subjective, this question can be addressed with mechanics. For example, if there are effects that apply to neutral-aligned creatures but not unaligned creatures, or vice versa.

Comment: Retracted my close vote based on the answers. Well done everyone!

Comment: @NautArch - Vote retracted. On another stack we close questions as duplicates when the answer to an existing question covers the new question. [I see that isn't the case here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## The reasoning behind their actions is what alignment *means*

You hit the nail on the head when you said

> unaligned is wild animals and true neutral being for intelligent creatures.

Alignment is a choice (most of the time), it's a philosophy and world outlook that a creature capable of thinking uses to interact with the world.

Animals (and certain other things like oozes, aberrations, monstrosities, whatever) lack the intelligence to *choose* to follow their alignment, they just do. A wolf or a cow or a black pudding doesn't choose to eat things and it doesn't have internal reasoning for its actions, it just reacts based on instinct. They all are amoral (lacking morality).

Carcer pointed out that outsiders like Fiends and Celestials also cannot choose their alignment, it's intrinsic to what they are, but they can still choose their behavior based on their alignment, whereas an unaligned thing doesn't choose at all.

Comment: To be precise, the text is also clear that for fiends and celestials, alignment is *not* a choice - they are what they are because it's fundamental to their nature. A devil is lawful evil by instinct and nature rather than by deliberate choice. The distinction is that the devil is smart enough to introspect and understand that its actions are lawful and evil, even if it doesn't have a real choice about behaving that way.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that outsiders that change alignment become something else entirely. Zariel as an example (p10 MTOF), outsiders like angels and devils lack a dual nature (soul and body) so their entire being changes if they "fall" or "rise" so to speak.

Comment: A devil can, in fact, upon introspection realize that they are a jerk and try to mend their ways. If they succeed however, they are no longer a devil. A devil that becomes chaotic becomes a demon, an angel that becomes evil becomes a devil, etc.

Comment: Then there was an article I read years ago that the Abyss was pseudo-sentient and that would mean that any "good" demons would serve only to instill more chaos as all the demons were extensions of the Abyss... but that goes down a really existential rabbit hole.

Comment: I think you're missing the mark a bit with fiends and celestials. Historically celestials have been Good-aligned because they're literally made out of Good-alignment. Compare a [regular badger against a celestial badger in 3.5](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/badger.htm). I don't believe this has changed for 5e (although alignment gets vaguer over time). I once wrote a [lengthy answer about this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41664/77) for Pathfinder, which mostly applies to core D&D.

Answer (score 17):

**Unaligned** specifically describes the "alignment" of creatures that lack the intellectual capacity to understand morals and ethics, as the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#AlignmentintheMultiverse) describes:

> Most creatures that lack the capacity for rational thought do not have alignments—they are unaligned. Such a creature is incapable of making a moral or ethical choice and acts according to its bestial nature. Sharks are savage predators, for example, but they are not evil; they have no alignment.

What this is meant to convey is that a creature that lacks the capacity for moral reasoning can do things which would absolutely be considered evil (or good, or lawful or chaotic) actions, *were it a creature with the capacity for moral reasoning*, but that doesn't make it actually evil (or good, or chaotic or lawful).

To take an example from popular culture, the common domestic housecat has a reputation for apparent sadism and cruelty based on how it hunts and "plays with its food". Were the cat an intelligent creature who chose to act that way towards its prey, it could quite fairly be called evil; it effectively often tortures prey animals for no practical purpose. However, a cat is not capable of moral reasoning, and it is not reasonable to ascribe an alignment to it - the game makes this explicit by calling such creatures **unaligned**.

Being unaligned is not the same as being neutral, since being neutral describes an intelligent creature that takes an overall neutral moral/ethical stance, but an unaligned creature could display any manner of cruel, altruistic, random or ordered behaviour without that having any impact on its mechanical alignment.

Comment: Heh, for beasts we used to have an ad hoc alignment: Hungry. :)